# Countdown timer window closing

Tags: java, swing

How can I close the timer window through code, when it completes it 30 sec duration.

Here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

class CountdownTimer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3613327984360590187L;

    public CountdownTimer() {

        setTitle("Countdown Timer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final long MINUTES = 30000;
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm : ss");
        final JLabel clock = new JLabel(sdf.format(new Date(MINUTES)), JLabel.CENTER);
        JLabel text = new JLabel("Time Remaining: ");
        int x = 0;
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            long x = MINUTES - 1000;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                clock.setText(sdf.format(new Date(x)));
                x -= 1000;
            }
        };
        new javax.swing.Timer(1000, actionListener).start();

        JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        jPanel.add(text);
        jPanel.add(clock);
        getContentPane().add(jPanel);
        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new CountdownTimer().setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

How can I close the timer window through code, when it completes it 30 sec duration.

Here is my code

Comment: Calling `dispose()` when `x` is `<=0`? What’s the question?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Comment: In his code it would be `dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(CountdownTimer.this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));`, though.

Comment: Most complicated way of saying `yourFrame.setVisible(false);`…

Comment: I assumed he wanted to really close the program.

Comment: @Holger , wouldn't that just hide the window? One of those: `dispose()`, `dispatchEvent()` or `System.exit(0)` would be what the OP wants, I guess.

Comment: Right, I overlooked the `setDefaultCloseOperation` call. Nevertheless, there is a simple form for every possibility: `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` → `setVisible(false)`, `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`  → `dispose()`, `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`  → `System.exit(0);`. In either case, `dispatchEvent` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    clock.setText(sdf.format(new Date(x)));
    x -= 1000;
    if (x < 0) // Add this line
        CountdownTimer.this.dispose(); // And this one too
}
```